# I cannot install applications because I don't know what to do with the authentication dialog

Tags: authentication

Whenever I try to download an application, I'm asked for authentication. With what? A password? I tried to use my Ubuntu-One password but that didn't work.

Comment: Can you try using your login password instead of you Ubuntu One password?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about installing things from the software centre.

You should be using your local user password. The one you set when you installed Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use your login password instead of your Ubuntu One password. Your login password is what you use to unlock the screensaver and login after you start up the computer.